# How to set up Dojo Doh unit testing on Travis CI?

Tags: dojo, travis-ci, doh

Does anyone have experience setting up dojo doh based unit testing on Travis CI?

I'd like to set up a webserver, and headless browser.

If possible, I'd also like to use dijit/robotx (which uses a java plugin) to further automate some tests.

From reading the Travis docs, I think it can be done, but if anyone has an example, or script to share, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you'll have any luck getting DOH Robot to work with a headless browser: it's very much attuned to generating low-level mouse and keyboard events.  Not sure that'll help you in a headless scenario anyway?

Plain DOH without Robot, however, should run fine headless.

It's up to you: if you think you need the sorts of things that DOH Robot provides, you may not want to restrict yourself to headless.  If you want headless, I think DOH might well do without DOH Robot.

I don't have headless browser experience, but I do have a full environment with DOH, DOH Robot, JSCoverage et al running on Jenkins on multiple real browsers.  (We use real browsers as even with compatibility layers, they're sufficiently different that it makes a massive difference.)

There's some good info over at
[another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256334/how-to-run-dojo-doh-unit-tests-through-jenkins) that covers the basics: you launch the browsers with Selenium, inject some JS into the browser to run your tests and suck the results back out, and then write them to disk.  I just write them out as JUnit format XML files, and my CI system slurps those up.